# Problemas com instalações no Raspian

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Eu estou com um problema, não estou conseguindo, instalar nenhum pacote no raspian, aparece o seguinte erro:

> Error: missing `server' JVM at`
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/arm/server/libjvm.so'.
>   Please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing
>   components. E: /etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore exited with
>   code 1. done. Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
>   ca-certificates-java openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf
>   openjdk-8-jdk-headless:armhf openjdk-8-jdk:armhf openjdk-8-jre:armhf
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro é por que você não tem nenhum pacote JDK ou JRE instalados em sua máquina, execute o download dos mesmos em: 
[JDK Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) 
Após instalar reinicie a máquina para que o Windows ou Linux identifique o JDK e JRE no PATCH do sistema.